# How to check str2 present in str1 and replace it with new str3 through command line without library function?

Tags: c, string, replace, command-line

I have error in my program called segmentation fault. I am using command line to pass parameters to function to check wether str2 is present in str1. How to replace it with str3 .Please help.

```
int main (int argc , char* argv[]) 

{

present (&argv[1] , &argv[2]) ;

return 0; 
}

My Function:

void present (char *str1[25] , char *str2[25])

{

 int i =0, j;

while (*str1[i] !=  '\0')


{
    
    if (*str1[i] == *str2[0])
    {
        j = 1;
        while ((*str2[j] != '\0' && *str1[ i + j ] != '\0') || (*str2[j] == *str1[j+i]))
        {
            j++;
        }
        if (*str2[j] == '\0')
        {
            printf(" Substring found at %d \n" , i + 1);
        }   
    }
    i++;
}

}
```

output required:

> The sky is blue sky water

replace sky with water

> The water is blue

Comment: i want without library function

Answer (score 0):

> You should put your code inside the Code Sample block (paste your
> code, select your code part, and press Ctrl + K).

`argv` is an array of pointers so `argv[1]` is a pointer to your first string, and `argv[2]` points to your second string. When you call `present (&argv[1], &argv[2])`, you're passing the address of `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` (the actual pointers), not the addresses of your strings.

To pass your strings to `present()`, what you should do is call `present (argv[1], argv[2])`. Then, in your `present()` function, your arguments should be `char* str1, char* str2`. After that, you must remove all unaries `*` since we changed the arguments.

Here's your code after all that above:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void present(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    int i=0, j;
    while(str1[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str1[i] == str2[0])
        {
            j = 1;
            while ((str2[j] != '\0' && str1[i + j] != '\0') || (str2[j] == str1[j + i]))
            {
                j++;
            }
            if (str2[j] == '\0')
            {
                printf(" Substring found at %d \n", i + 1);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    present(argv[1], argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

one more note: your code seems only find where in str1 **match the first character** of str2. Which is not correct.

```
str1 = "hello world"
str2 = "orl"
result = 5, 8 // (positions of 'o' in str1)
```

Comment: can you modify my code with according to my output without lib function lee ! Please !!!! I am new to it :')

Comment: The sky is blue sky water --
replace sky with water --
The water is blue

Comment: you can divide your problem into 2 parts:  
1. find: edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631538/5055747) so that it return the found substr position ie `found_pos`.  
2. replace: split `str1` into smaller parts: `str1` = `str1_1` ("the ") + `str2` ("sky") + `str1_2` (" is blue"), copy `str1_1` to `new_str`, append `str3` ("water"), append `str1_2` -> `new_str = "the water is blue"`